# Is it possible to prove big oh/big omega using graphs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graphing-functions

I'm having a very, very hard time understand them. For example a question asking prove 42 is theta 1. Is it possible to use graphs?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometric intuition, perhaps represented by a graph, can be useful. However, in this case it is perhaps not necessary. We have a function $f(n)$ given by $f(n)=42$ for all $n$. We have another function $g(n)$ given by $g(n)=1$ for all $n$. Boring functions, they are both constant.

I am not sure what your local definition of $\Theta$ is, the definitions can vary a little. We want to show that $f(n)$ is $\Theta(g(n))$. If you look at the definition, it means that there  there is an $N$, and positive constants $k_1$ and $k_2$, such that if $n\gt N$ then
$$k_1 g(n)\lt f(n)\lt k_2 g(n).$$
We can take $N=1$, it doesn't matter. Let $k_1=1$ and $k_2=50$.

Certainly $k_1 g(n)=g(n)=1\lt f(n)$. Also, $42=f(n)\lt 50=50g(n)$. So we are finished.

**Informally** we needed to show that $f(n)$ is (possibly only after a while) caught between a constant times $g(n)$ and another constant times $g(n)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. So for example, if we had a harder question, let's say (n-7)^2 is Theta(n^2). Is it done as so:  

k1g(n) < f(n) < k2g(n),  
For example make k1 = 1 and k2 = 10,  

n^2 < n^2-49 < 10n^2  

Which I assume is true?  

Thanks for the help once again.

Comment: I take it $f(n)=(n-7)^2$, $g(n)=n^2$, we want to show $f(n)$ is $\Theta(g(n))$.  So we want $k_1n^2 \lt (n-7)^2\lt k_2 n^2$. The right-side inequality is OK with $k_2=1$ **as long as** $n\gt 7$. For the left side inequality, want $k_1n^2<(n-7)^2$. If $n \gt 14$, then $n-7\gt n/2$, so can take $k_1=1/4$.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at this [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations), you can see you should only show there exist positive constants $k_1$ and $k_2$ such that $k_1\cdot1\leq 42 \leq k_2\cdot 1$.

For this particular case you can take $k_1=k_2=42$.

Not sure if using graphs is of any help in this case. In general it might be possible to use graphs to get intuition, but a formal proof would require a closer analysis of the growth rates of the functions involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)!